# How to hide include layout inside custom dialog in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layout under `<include>` and i want to hide on `radio button` checked.

**My XML code**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/maid_full_emp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <include
            layout="@layout/maid_full_emp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/maid_part_emp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <include
            layout="@layout/maid_part_emp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**[Custom dialog code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26207126/)**

[Logcat output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26207133/)

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: aminfocraft.harsh.mymaidfinder, PID: 29548
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at aminfocraft.harsh.mymaidfinder.Activity.MaidSearchEmpPak.MaidSearchEmpNew.onCheckedChanged(MaidSearchEmpNew.java:429)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:165)
        at aminfocraft.harsh.mymaidfinder.Activity.MaidSearchEmpPak.MaidSearchEmpNew.assignViews1(MaidSearchEmpNew.java:370)
        at aminfocraft.harsh.mymaidfinder.Activity.MaidSearchEmpPak.MaidSearchEmpNew.searchUser(MaidSearchEmpNew.java:386)
        at aminfocraft.harsh.mymaidfinder.Activity.MaidSearchEmpPak.MaidSearchEmpNew.onOptionsItemSelected(MaidSearchEmpNew.java:296)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3219)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:380)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
```

Comment: add you code in question

Comment: i have added code via url  visit :- https://paste.ubuntu.com/26207126/

Comment: you need to add you code in question rather give link

Comment: while adding code i am getting 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.ERROR

Comment: you can even hide the layouts from your include layout roots. just findviewById() the rootlayout of your included layouts and set their visibilities as you want.

Comment: where you assign views, there get the root layouts by id's

Comment: i have tried it but didn't work for me

Comment: just give ids to the root layouts of both included layouts and in place of assigning views R.layout.yourview to R.id.rootlayoutid;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `R.id instead` of `R.layout`

```
maid_full_emp = (LinearLayout )dialog.findViewById(R.id.maid_full_emp);
maid_part_emp = (LinearLayout )dialog.findViewById(R.id.maid_part_emp);
```

**instead of**

```
maid_full_emp = (LinearLayout )dialog.findViewById(R.layout.maid_full_emp);
 maid_part_emp = (LinearLayout )dialog.findViewById(R.layout.maid_part_emp);
```